# Custom stopwords for PyLucene

Tags: python, filter, set, stop-words, pylucene

In PyLucene, there is a filter called `StopFilter` which filters tokens based on given stopwords.  The example call is as follows:

```
result = StopFilter(True, result, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET)
```

It seems like it should be easy to replace the argument for the set of stop words, but this is actually a bit challenging:

```
>>> StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET

<Set: [but, be, with, such, then, for, no, will, not, are, and, their, if, this, on, into, a, or, there, in, that, they, was, is, it, an, the, as, at, these, by, to, of]>
```

This is a `Set`, which is not able to be implemented:

```
>>> Set()

NotImplementedError: ('instantiating java class', <type 'Set'>)
```

It was suggested elsewhere to use a `PythonSet`, which comes with PyLucene, but it turns out that this is not an instance of a `Set`, and cannot be used with a `StopFilter`.

How can one give a `StopFilter` a new set of stop words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this halfway through writing this question via this thread on the pylucene dev list:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-pylucene-dev/201202.mbox/thread

You can define a `StopFilter` using a custom list as follows:

```
mystops = HashSet(Arrays.asList(['a','b','c']))
result = StopFilter(True, result, mystops)
```

Comment: Yep.  In Java, Set() is an interface.  To instantiate, you need an implementation of that interface like HashSet()